# How do I put a box around my Flot graph?

Tags: jquery, css, border, flot, box

I’ve created a graph with Flot (using JQuery 1.11).  I would like to have a dark box around my graph with the grid being lighter in the background, similar to the main Flot example — http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/basic-usage/index.html .  So I have this HTML on which the FLot wraps itself …

```
<div class="demo-container">
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:800px; height:500px;"></div>
</div>
```

and then I add this CSS

```
.demo-container {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

But this puts a box around my main container and not the graph.  How do I get a box around the graph?  My attempted stab at this is in this Fiddle — http://jsfiddle.net/y16h8LmL/5/ .  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the value of `borderWidth`

```
grid: {
  margin: 10,
  labelMargin: 5,
  labelWidth: 20,
  hoverable: true,
  clickable: true,
  tickColor: "#efefef",
  borderWidth: 0, // Here for the width
  borderColor: "#efefef" // Here for the color
},
```

Here is [your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/y16h8LmL/9/)  :)

Comment: Thanks but that's not quite what I want.  You see how in their example the border is to the right of the y-axis and just above the x-axis -- http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/basic-usage/index.html  ?  I want to do that.  IN your example, the border surrounds everything, labels and all.

Comment: @Dave I had you wrong, answer is updated _(with the timestamps, I edited it during your comment)_and match the flot demo you gave us :)

Answer (score 0):

This configurations are in your *javascript* code not *css*:

In your js code, *grid* section:
change:

```
tickColor: "#efefef",
borderWidth: 0,
borderColor: "#efefef"
```

To:

```
tickColor: "#cccccc",
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: "#000000"
```

Or any *color* or *width* you prefer.